# React component lifecycle componentWillReceiveProps deprecation causes problem with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, deprecated, componentwillreceiveprops

I have 2 components, one that is used to add new post to an array of posts and another component that maps through that array of posts and lists them on the page.

I want to add the new post to the top of the array with `unshift()`, but ever since `componentWillReceiveProps` was deprecated, I've been struggling to find a solution with the new `getDerivedStateFromProps` method.

---

Here is Postform.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { createPost } from "../actions/postActions";

class PostForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: "",
      body: "",
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this); // Bind onChange event
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this); // Bind onSubmit event
  }

  // Set state when changing input value
  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const post = {
      title: this.state.title,
      body: this.state.body,
    };

    this.props.createPost(post);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Add Post</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div>
            <label>Title: </label>
            <br />
            <input
              type="text"
              name="title"
              onChange={this.onChange}
              value={this.state.title}
            />
          </div>
          <br />
          <div>
            <label>Body: </label>
            <br />
            <textarea
              name="body"
              onChange={this.onChange}
              value={this.state.body}
            />
          </div>
          <br />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

PostForm.propTypes = {
  createPost: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default connect(null, { createPost })(PostForm);
```

Here is Posts.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchPosts } from "../actions/postActions";

class Posts extends Component {
  state = {
    newPost: this.props.newPost,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchPosts();
  }

  // The new way I am struggling with
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.newPost !== state.newPost) {
      props.posts.unshift(props.newPost);
    }
    return null;
  }

   // The old way, now renamed with UNSAFE_ prefix
  /* UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.newPost) {
      this.props.posts.unshift(nextProps.newPost);
    }
  } */

  render() {
    const postItems = this.props.posts.map((post) => (
      <div key={post.id + Math.random()}>
        <h3>{post.title}</h3>
        <p>{post.body}</p>
      </div>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Posts</h1>
        {postItems}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Posts.propTypes = {
  fetchPosts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  posts: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  newPost: PropTypes.object,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  posts: state.posts.items,
  newPost: state.posts.item,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts })(Posts);
```

---

The problem is that `getDerivedStateFromProps` is called twice (initial mount and every render),

unlike `componentWillReceiveProps` which is called only once.

This causes the newPost to be added twice to the array and thus it shows double on the page too.

---

I am using Redux here, so the state should be in the store (mostly is), but I've added a state for the `Posts.js` component since the `getDerivedStateFromProps` won't otherwise work (as far as I've tried).

---

In a nutshell: How do I add the newPost to the props-array inside the `getDerivedStateFromProps` (or other lifecycle method) without getting double results?

Comment: The best way to do it is to add another component above to manage the state. `Posts` should be a stateless component.

Comment: You should NEVER modify `props` it is a violation of React one-way-dataflow. `props.posts.unshift(props.newPost);`

Comment: @Rostyslav Ah, of course. Forgot about that. Still kind of new to React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getDerivedStateFromProps is invoked right before calling the render method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing as per react docs : https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

You already seem to be using redux, thus once you have done createPost why don't you do array.unshift while updating your posts in the Redux Store and thus your store will hold the state.posts.items with your latest post on top.

Comment: Yes, this solved it. Thanks! But there is still some magic here I don't understand. I simply added the action payload to the unshift in my reducer and I removed all 3 following from Posts.js: state, getDerivedStateFromProps and UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps. I noticed that the newPost needs to be in mapStateToProps for this to work, but I don't really get why.